# Windows form application using Visual Studio c++, that links to a CUDA project

Tags: c++, windows, forms, cuda

I am trying to implement a Windows Form Application using Visual Studio C++ that links to a CUDA project.

1. I created WFA.
2. Then I try to dynamically link the application to CUDA project by browsing the .dll in the Add Reference part of the Project Properties. But it said "Could not add ... it is not a .NET assembly or registered ActiveX control".
3. Thus I add the .obj of the CUDA project to the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies part with the .lib files that are required to run CUDA in WFA project. Then I got "fatal error LNK1313: pure module detected; cannot link with ijw/native modules" error.
4. I changed the Common Language Runtime Support from "Pure MSIL Common Language..." to "Common Language..." but then msvcrtd.lib and libcmt.lib is conflicted. This error disappears when the .obj files of CUDA project are deleted from the "Additional Dependencies".

Since CUDA project's runtime is MT  and WFA project's is MT dll, this error occurs. I changed the runtime of WFA to MT, but then "error D8016 : '/MTd' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible" error occurs.

Since /clr is required for "System::" being recognized, I cannot get rid of the /clr option.

Do you have any suggestion to create a windows form application using Windows c++ that links to a cuda project in the easiest way? Or if there are easier way I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: Your question is incredibly hard to read in its current form. Could you break it into paragraphs for the sake of everyone's eyes?

Answer (score 1):

I think your WFA app is a managed  C++ .NET application using CLR. You are trying to include the unmanaged CUDA DLL as  if it were  a CLR Assembly or a COM Object.  Thus VS is saying /MT (use  unmanaged Multi-Threaded C run-time)  and /CLR is not compatible.

So you need to either wrap the  CUDA DLL in CLR object or use a .NET Binding for CUDA in your project.  Try downloading CUDA.NET  and incorporate that into you project as  reference.

http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/CUDA.NET/